# How to query self referencing table

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table of employees.
Each employee has a manager, and each manager has a manager and so on.
So for a manager I want to do a query so that I have all my team members, and I have all their team members and so on.
What is the best way to do this in a EF Linq statement.
Ideally I want a list of employees and know which team each one is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 % sure how you solve this in EF, and I think it could end up with many queries (one for every manager if you are unlucky). As I would do it is to start with your top Employee and get all the employees that has that manager as a manager. Then I would recursively take all the manager in the set of employees you just got and extract their ids. When you have all the ids you can query the db for employees that has any of the ids as their manager.

Do you get my point? This will result in a query per level instead of one query per manager. But maybe EF resolves that issue, I'm not sure. But I think you need to do it recursively.

I would aim for something like:

```
public IList<Employees> GetEmployeesForManager(int managerId)
{
    return GetEmployeesForManagers(new List<int>() { managerId });
}

public IList<Employees> GetEmployeesForManagers(IList<int> managerIds)
{
    var listOfEmployees = // Get the employees
    var listOfManagers = listOfEmployees.Where(y => y.IsManager).Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
    if(listOfManagers.Count >= 0)
        listOfEmployees.AddRange(GetEmployeesForManagers(listOfManagers));
    return listOfEmployees;
}
```

Comment: And then I would definitely go for my solution :). I guess you can do it with some really complicated lambdas, but what is the point when you can keep it simple? This solution will guarantee you want have more queries than you have levels in your organization.

Comment: The code needs tidying up. When adding to the collection you should use the AddRange method

Comment: Change to AddRange, the only way I've compiled the code is in firefox so did get an error message. Did the answer solved your problem?